# Multiple Joomla Admin websites

Tags: php, joomla, administrator, user-registration

I want to make a Joomla based website with multiple user rights each for a single component. For example: two different user groups with each access to their own component in the backend (Usergroup 1: component A & Usergroup 2: component B).
Is it possible to have separate login urls for each user?
www.example.com/usergroup1 & www.example.com/usergroup2

I know how to make seperate templates for each usergroups, but want them available through a specific url

Thanks for your help!

**
EDIT
**

Unfortunately it seems impossible to make multiple joomla backends. I thought it would take a few steps to accomplish... Anyway, i'm rebuilding my component now to give it front access.

Comment: ? http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=673&t=747817

Comment: Why don't you just use ACL to give each group manager access to their respective component? THis is long there are tons of other explanations you can find http://www.slideshare.net/careytech/role-based-acl-2013

Comment: Thx for your answers, I already downloaded the ACL manager extension, and I know how to restrict access to a single component. I already made a specific admin theme for the users. But i simply want them to access their backend through another URL as /administrator

Comment: You could make a second application or something.  It's really hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish, why don't you just work on providing access via the front end? I think you need to look at it from a different perspective e.g. why is it that having a different url is important when what the users see can be completely different?

Comment: Thanks for your response, i'm working on access rights through frontend now. Then I can change login URL. Its because i want to seperate login design for backend users and users who just have access to my component. Therefore I need seperate URLS. Anyway, I found it's really hard to change Joomla administrator's URL